# 74HC125/74AC125 vs. 74AHC125N/74AHC125 for overvoltage tolerant USBtinyISP 2.0

Tags: buffer, over-voltage-protection, isp, 7400

The [schematic of the USBtinyISP 2.0](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/6834) makes a point of using a non-inverting buffer IC with overvoltage tolerant inputs:

> Only 74AHC125N is 5V compliant at lower VCC!

I bought a couple of USBtinyISP 2.0 boards from Aliexpress, a few years ago and they don't use a 74AHC125N but an [NXP 74HC125](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT125.pdf) which isn't overvoltage tolerant, AFAICS.

However, I just connected the device to a 3.3V powered ATmega328p and it seems to work fine. That means I opened JP3 to disconnect USB 5V VCC from the ISP connector and connected VCC to 3.3V. Flashing and settings fuses works most of the time, so far.

Is it just luck that it works?

Or is NXP just relabeling the overvoltage tolerant [NXP 74AHC125](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/asynchronous-interface-logic/buffers-inverters-drivers/series/74AHC125-74AHCT125.html) as 74HC125 and perhaps the Chinese manufacturer knows/speculates that?

I guess the motivation for using the overvoltage *intolerant* version to save a few cents on that IC?

---

Btw, it doesn't seem too easy to get pre-built USBtinyISP 2.0 boards which are overvoltage  tolerant.

Even the one [Sparkfun sells](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pocket-avr-programmer-hookup-guide) just uses a 74AC125 buffer IC which isn't overvoltage tolerant. Sparkfun warns about using it with anything other than 5V:

> Warning! Be careful using this feature! It will output 5V and only 5V! If you're working with a 3.3V or 1.8V system, make sure this switch is in the No Power position and use a logic level converter.

The recommendation to use a logic-level converter (they also sell such boards) seems odd, because the original design doesn't have this limitation, i.e. they simply could have used an overvoltage tolerant IC!

Especially, since [Sparkfun markets](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825) their product with:

> This product is a collaboration with Limor Fried [who created the above schematic, AFAICS]. A portion of each sales goes back to them for product support and continued development.

---

Another curious thing, one time I forgot to connect the 3.3V to the USBtinyISP connector and flashing still worked! I'm wondering how the buffer IC was powered then ...

Comment: Related: [74HC125 vs 74HCT125](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/253183/56807) and [Which 74xx logic families are overvoltage tolerant on their outputs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/31601/56807)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luck has nothing to do with this. HC and AHC series are different and must be chosen and used within their specs. It is unlikely that a company would label same chip as AHC and HC as circuits may depend on their specific behaviour.

The 74HC series does not tolerate input voltages beyond supply voltage. It has clamping diodes on input to VCC and GND, so if it is powered by 3.3V from target and input comes from a 5V programmer MCU, the 5V signal current gets pushed to 3.3V supply and it might push the 3.3V supply voltage up if it has a light load. So it will stress the 5V MCU output pin, 74HC125 input clamping diodes, and the target as the supply voltage may rise above absolute maximum ratings.

At the same time, if you have a 3.3V target powering the 74HC, the 74HC output voltage is also 3.3V. According to AVR datasheet specs, 3.3V signal is not guaranteed to read as high logic level so it may not work. Even worse with lower target voltages than 3.3V.

The programmer schematic seems to be quite gimmicky and dubious. By design it uses software bit-banging for USB communication because the MCU has no hardware peripheral for USB. That would be technically OK, but since the MCU can't work at high enough speeds at 3.3V supply that would match USB data logic levels, the MCU needs to run at 5V supply and resistors and zeners are needed to limit 5V from GPIO from destroying PC USB data pins.

Also there is a 100uF capacitor on USB 5V line, and that's 10x more what USB specifications allow without limiting the surge current. Some PCs may trigger an overcurrent event and shut dowb the port. It might also trigger some fuses or polyfuses on some PCs.

This design really makes you think if you even want to plug it in to your computers or will it work programming non-5V target devices.